# Permission denied creating folder after setting parent folder as www-data user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, apache-2.4

in my `phpinfo` configuration, i see the following:

```
User/Group  www-data(33)/33
```

In my directory `/var/www/html/pluto-php/public/` I see the following for the `data directory inside this path:`

```
4 drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 19 23:25 data
```

I also see the following for the `pluto-php directory`

```
4 drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Sep 16 21:49 pluto-php
```

I set the owner and group for the data dir to www-data. Somehow, after all of this, I still get this error in my `php code` when running a php script which **creates a directory inside the data directory**:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/pluto-php/vendor/pluto/src/Pluto/Stdlib/FilesystemUtils.php on line 32
```

I tried doing `apache2ctl restart` and that did nothing.

I've followed along every tutorial on google search and im stuck here.

UPDATE:

Here is my process list

```
    root@yonaton-Lenovo-V570:/var/www/html# ps aux | grep apache
    root      3234  0.0  0.6 409908 37092 ?        Ss   Sep28   0:09 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data  8516  0.3  0.2 410888 16988 ?        S    10:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data  8517  0.0  0.1 409940 10632 ?        S    10:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data  8518  0.0  0.1 409940 10632 ?        S    10:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data  8519  0.0  0.1 409940 10632 ?        S    10:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data  8520  0.0  0.1 409940 10632 ?        S    10:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data  8521  0.0  0.1 409940 10632 ?        S    10:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    root      8523  0.0  0.0  21292  1088 pts/1    S+   10:41   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

Comment: Check what user are running apache
`ps aux | grep apache`

Comment: @YagoNobre updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`www-data` must have write access to the entire tree.

You can execute `chown -R www-data:yourgroup /var/www/html/pluto-php`, where `yourgroup` is the group name of your user (avoid `root` for security reasons). If you don't specify your groupname, you won't be able to write and read in the data directory.

Next add the right permissions by executing `chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/pluto-php`.

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied is invariably an OS level issue. First make sure the user you think the process is running as really is the relevant user. You seem to have done that, but also verify you are not running something like suexec, mpm_itk or mod_ruid which can change the UID indvidual requests run as.

Next, check the path you are trying to write to is traversable by the user (in this case www-data). The `namei` command can help here:

`namei -mo /var/www/html/pluto-php/public/`

Next verify if some OS level security software such as SELinux or Apparmor is running and if it is, determine if it is interfering with your process writing to that directory.

Finally a directory permission of 0777 is never needed. 1777 possibly, but if you need  the permissions set to 0777 in order to get it to work, something else is wrong.